# How do I get starting/ending indexes of all differences between two strings in Java?

Tags: java, difference

In Java, I'm looking to obtain a list of all the start and end indexes of differences between two strings. I see how I can get the starting index of the first difference between two strings but I can't quite figure out how to finish this problem.

I found code in StringUtils : indexOfDifference(String, String), which gets the starting index of the first difference between two strings, but I don't see a way to get the ending index of that first difference nor do I see a way to get all the rest of the starting/ending indexes of all differences between the two strings.

For example, if I have these two strings:
origStr : "Hello World"
revisedStr : "Help the World23"

I want all the ranges of differences between orig and revised strs.

Any guidance would be very helpful.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import difflib.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestDiffUtils {

    public TestDiffUtils() {

    }

    // Helper method to read the files to compare into memory, convert them to a list of Strings which can be used by the DiffUtils library for comparison
    private static List fileToLines(String filename) {
        List lines = new LinkedList();
        String line;
        try {
            URL path = TestDiffUtils.class.getResource(filename);
            File f = new File(path.getFile());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lines;
    }

    private static void printUnifiedDiffs(List<String> diffs){
        for(String diff : diffs){
            System.out.println(diff);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compares two Strings, and returns the index at which the
     * Strings begin to differ.
     *
     * For example,
     * <code>indexOfDifference("i am a machine", "i am a robot") -> 7</code>
     *
     * <pre>
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference(null, null) = -1
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("", "") = -1
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("", "abc") = 0
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("abc", "") = 0
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("abc", "abc") = -1
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("ab", "abxyz") = 2
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("abcde", "abxyz") = 2
     * StringUtils.indexOfDifference("abcde", "xyz") = 0
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param str1  the first String, may be null
     * @param str2  the second String, may be null
     * @return the index where str2 and str1 begin to differ; -1 if they are equal
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public static int startingIndexOfDifference(String str1, String str2) {
        if (str1 == str2) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (str1 == null || str2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < str1.length() && i < str2.length(); ++i) {
            if (str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i < str2.length() || i < str1.length()) {
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static void doBasicLineByLineDiff(Boolean doLargeFileTest) {
        String origFileName;
        String revisedFileName;

        if( doLargeFileTest )
        {
            origFileName = "test_large_file.xml";
            revisedFileName = "test_large_file_revised.xml";
        }else{
            origFileName = "originalFile.txt";
            revisedFileName = "revisedFile.txt";
        }

        List<String> originalLines = fileToLines(origFileName);
        List<String> revisedLines = fileToLines(revisedFileName);

        Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalLines, revisedLines);
        List<String> diffs = DiffUtils.generateUnifiedDiff(origFileName, revisedFileName, originalLines, patch, 0);     // 0 = don't show any lines of context around different lines
        List<Delta> deltas = patch.getDeltas();
        for(Delta delta : deltas){
            int diffLine = delta.getOriginal().getPosition()+1;
            System.out.println("[" + diffLine + " : (" + startingIndexOfDifference((String) delta.getOriginal().getLines().get(0), (String) delta.getRevised().getLines().get(0)) + ",<todo-diffEndIndexHere>)]");
        }

        // printUnifiedDiffs(diffs);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doBasicLineByLineDiff(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried that isn't working](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Edited to show code I have so far. I can get the starting index of the first diff but I need the ranges of indexes for all diffs between two strings.

Comment: I feel like you could do this recursively.

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes, what's going on?

Comment: What is `DiffUtils`?

Comment: @Andreas https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-diff-utils/downloads

Comment: So `DiffUtils.diff()` takes `List<?>`, and you call it with lines (`List<String>`) to find line differences. Why not reuse it to find character differences between two lines, i.e. `List<Character>`? It already has all the complexity of identifying where a difference ends, and commonality begins again, repeatedly. Don't try to implement that yourself, when you already have a library that can do it.

Comment: You need at least a definition of what you mean by "range of difference" in a string.  What would indicate the end of a range of difference, and the start of the next one?  How do you take insertions and deletions into account?

Comment: @antlersoft range means start index and end index of the diff. I'm not sure how I'm going to handle insertions and deletions properly. I was hoping there was a library written or method somewhere that can show me how to go about doing this weird task.

Comment: @Andreas Interesting idea ... didn't even realize I could do a List of any objects in diff() ... that might be the solution.

Comment: @Andreas If you post your suggestion as answer to use List<?> feature of DiffUtils.diff() I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DiffUtils.diff()` takes `List<?>`, and you call it with lines (`List<String>`) to find line differences.

You can reuse it to find character differences between two lines, i.e. `List<Character>`.

It already has all the complexity of identifying where a difference ends, and commonality begins again, repeatedly. Don't try to implement that yourself, when you already have a library that can do it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I missed this minor detail because of some of the names in the DiffUtils class. Andreas pointed it out and sometimes the simplest solution is the best solution.